# Prove $A$ is independent of every event $B \in \mathcal{F}$ if $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: probability, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a random probability space and $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

How can one prove that if $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$, then $A$ is independent of every event $B \in \mathcal{F}$?

I think  if $P(B) \in \{0,1\}$, then it follows that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ for all events of $A$, meaning that $B$ is independent of every event A inlcuding itself. Especially $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ are independent of every event $A$.

But I don't think that this answers the question.

I also want to know how one can prove that $A$ is independent of $B \in \mathcal{F}$ if and only if $A$ and $B^c$ are independent.

Here I have

$$
P(A) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c) \\
P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)
$$

Is that enough for a "proof"? Because the probability that $A$ has occurred and $B$ has not occurred is by definition $P(A\cap B^c)$ and similarly the probability that $A$ has occurred and $B$ has is $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: You haven't quite finished.  You need to show that $\Pr(A\cap B^c)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)$, but you're very close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(A)=0$ then $P(A \cap B) \le P(A) = 0$. Can you conclude $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$?

If $P(A) = 1$ then $P(A^c \cap B) \le P(A^c) = 0$. Note also $P(A \cap B) = P(B) - P(A^c \cap B)$. Can you conclude from here?

---

For the second question, you are almost there, but you should write the remaining steps explicitly:

$$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) = P(A) - P(A) P(B) = \cdots = P(A) P(B^c).$$
Can you fill in the missing steps?